# VS Code/Git branch view?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I just started using VS Code with Git integration. For some time I had the layout like this: [image]

I had the Source Control dropdown with the little branch icon next to it, making it easy to switch branches. For some reason it's now gone and what I have is:

[image]

How do I get the first view back? I know how to switch branches, the question is not about this - the question is why this view changed and how to get it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Go to Settings

[image: Settings]

Then search for "Source control provider", and check the "Always Show providers".

[image: Source control provider]